# Django REST - Ex1 - Serialization

Tags: django

We had given task for Django REST - Ex1 - Serialization, task is attach in below screen shot -

[Task Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jyMe.png)

For the same task we had written code as -

view.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse,HttpResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from wishes.models import Wish
from wishes.serializers import WishSerializer


@csrf_exempt
def wish_list(request):
    pass
    """
    List all wishes or create a new wish
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
      serializer = WishSerializer(Wish)
      serializer.data
      return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

        #Write method Implementation here

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
        #Write method Implementation here

@csrf_exempt
def wish_detail(request,pk):
    pass
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a birthday wish.
    """
    try:
        wish = Wish.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Wish.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass
        #Write method Implementation here

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        pass
        #Write method Implementation here


    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        pass
        #Write method Implementation here
```

Our concerns related to code part is

```
      serializer = WishSerializer(Wish)
      serializer.data
      return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

in this serializer = WishSerializer(Wish) having error as - `Too many positional arguments for function callpylint(too-many-function-args)`

when we execute required code then we getting error as below. Hence we need expertise advice what went wrong in our code-

```
self.assertEqual(res.status_code, row['response']['status_code'])
AssertionError: 500 != 200
Stdout:
{'response': {'body': [], 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'status_code': 200}, 'request': {'body': {}, 'headers': {}, 'url': '/wishes', 'method': 'GET'}}
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from wishes.models import Wish

#Add WishSerializer implementation here
def WishSerializer():
    pass
```

test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient
import json

class RestTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.test_1 = []
        with open('TestData/http001.json') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.test_1.append(line)

    def test_get_all_wishes(self):
        client = RequestsClient()
        for ro in self.test_1:
            row = json.loads(ro)
            print (row)
            res = {}
            if row['request']['method'] == "GET":
                res = client.get('http://localhost:8000' +
                                 row['request']['url'] + '/')
            elif row['request']['method'] == "POST":
                res = client.post(
                    'http://localhost:8000' + row['request']['url'] + '/', json=row['request']['body'])
            self.assertEqual(res.status_code, row['response']['status_code'])
            if row['response']['headers'] != {}:
                self.assertEqual(
                    res.headers['Content-Type'], row['response']['headers']['Content-Type'])
            if row['response']['body'] != {}:
                response = json.loads(res.text)
                self.assertEqual(response, row['response']['body'])
```

Comment: Please provide your serializer class. At `serializer = WishSerializer(Wish)` where are you getting the `Wish`-intance ? It seems you are using `drf`. You should use `from rest_framework.response import Response` and `return Response()`. If your `Wish` is a `queryset` and not only a single instance, you have to add `WishSerializer(Wish, many=True)`

Comment: Your serializer is empty therefore it isn´t gonne work. Set up your serializer class as a `ModelSerializer` and it will work.

Comment: so our view.py is correct but issues in serializers.py?

Comment: Yeah, but I haven´t tested the code. Have you taken a look at the `drf`-tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse,HttpResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from wishes.models import Wish
from wishes.serializers import WishSerializer


@csrf_exempt
def wish_list(request):
    """
    List all wishes or create a new wish
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
      qs = Wish.objects.all()
      serializer = WishSerializer(qs, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
      serializer = WishSerializer(data=request.data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response(serializer.data, status=201)  

@csrf_exempt
def wish_detail(request,pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a birthday wish.
    """
    try:
        wish = Wish.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Wish.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer =  WishSerializer(wish)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = WishSerializer(instance=wish, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)


    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        wish.delete()
        return Response(status=204)
```

Comment: getting error as    
File "/projects/challenge/wishes/views.py", line 3

    from rest_framework.response import 

                                       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Parse the request with `JSONParser()` and add data to your serializer. Take a look at the tutorial. Your code is quite identical.

Comment: please provide link, how to Parse the request with JSONParser() and add data to your serialize

Comment: [drf-tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Comment: we check tutorial n tried code getting same ```Traceback (most recent call last): File "/projects/challenge/wishes/tests.py", line 25, in test_get_all_wishes self.assertEqual(res.status_code, row['response']['status_code']) AssertionError: 500 != 200 Stdout: {'response': {'body': [], 'status_code': 200, 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}, 'request': {'method': 'GET', 'body': {}, 'url': '/wishes', 'headers': {}}}``` error